# Reinit functions after ajax page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pageload

The issue is that after the `.load()` function gets triggered, the predefined functions don't execute.

I am trying to re-init my functions after ajax `.load();` function.

Here's my sample code:

```
var myApp = {
myObj: {
    key1: value1,
    key1: value1
},
activities:{
    myFunction1: function() {
        // my activity 1
    },
    myFunction2: function() {
        // my activity 2
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {    
    myApp.activities.myFunction1(); // This function executes    
    $('.load-next-page').load(function() {          
        // next page loaded         
        myApp.activities.myFunction1(); // This function doesn't trigger, Need to trigger this function    
    });

});
```

Comment: I think it should be `$('.load-next-page').load('load-next-page-link', function() {

    myApp.activities.myFunction1(); 

});`

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the `$.load` function. Try re-reading this http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Pass the `url` to `load`

Comment: @HenryTran: Actually this is sample code. The original one is is loading the content as expected. The problem only that the functions doesn't work after the function call .load();

Comment: @AbhijeetSalunkhe what is $('.load-next-page') ? is it an iframe , a div etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("load", ".load-next-page", function(){
    myApp.activities.myFunction1();
});
```

Each time document element is loaded the function is triggered.
If IE8 is not a constraint, use the DOMSubtreeModified event for this.

Answer (score 0):

try `Promises` like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/) 
and then using `.then()`

or [jquery `.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) 
like `$( "div" ).promise().done(function() {...`

you can read more about it [hare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [hare](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)